# Can fire survival cables be used in underground tunnels for emergencies?

Tags: cables

I would like to know where fire survival cables can be used
https://www.pyrosales.com.au/fire-survival-mi-cable - states a few including tunnels, shopping centres etc. Where are they mainly used and are they only ever installed for emergencies?

Comment: You probably have a more specific question in mind. If so, stating it would be useful. | Another location is MBTs (Main Battle Tanks).

Answer (score 2):

> ... where fire survival cables can be used ..."

Anywhere.

> ... are they only ever installed for emergencies?

No they are installed for always *including* fires.

Check the prices to see why we don't use them everywhere.